# Display the most recent entry in a given week

Tags: sql

I have got multiple entries in each week. I would like to see the most recent entry in the current week and the most recent entry the previous week.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: At the very least post your schema and provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Take a look into the MAX() function to find most recent records, and date functions to filter by week.  You'll have better success getting answers if you show some attempted work.  Also it helps to know your DBMS and some sample data / desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

Query #1:
For the most recent entry this week (including today), try max([DateFieldGoesHere]).

Query #2:
For the most recent entry in the previous week, it depends on how the week is defined.

- If your week starts "7 days from now", then you can do a WHERE clause with a datediff of 7 days.
- If you week starts on Sunday, then your WHERE will have to take that into consideration.

The datediff functions available to you will depend on the technologies you are using.